# Shorten text if line brake appears in a div

Tags: php, html

I have a webpage with names in DIVs. Some names are very long and produces line brakes on some screen widths. In those cases I would like to shorten the first word (eg First Name) to the initial (eg first letter) and keep the rest as is (ex David van Macleaoderson -> D van Macleaoderson) for lesser line brakes.

How do I detect a browser rendered line brake in a DIV and then perform a shorten operation?

Answer (score 1):

You can first count the length of that div (means how many character adjust in that div) 
for example div adjust only 20 character

```
$divMaxVal = 20;

$name = "David van Macleaoderson";
 $stringcnt= strlen($name); // Count the length of string i.e. 23
if($stringcnt>$divMaxVal){ // Check whether string count ($stringcnt) value is greater than $divMaxVal or not

//StringCount Value greater than $divMaxVal

    $split = explode(' ', $name,2); // Explode the  String in first occurance of delimeter
   $firstchar = $split[0];   // =David 
  echo  $firstchar[0].' '.$split[1]; // =D van Macleaoderson // combine the first character from David (i.e.Explode array 1st value ) and  Explode array 2nd value 
}else{
// if StringCount Value is not  greater than $divMaxVal
  echo $name;  
}
```

Comment: Thanks for a quick answer! But then I need to do multiple variants of this to every screen width. Is there a chance of counting rendered lines? If more than 1 line do this (split explode)?

Comment: For multiple screen width every time you have to provide value to variable $divMaxVal . But its not a good solution.

Comment: @DanielWaj you were not mentioned a multiple screen in question. If we leave multiple screen then according to youe question above answer is correct.

Comment: Sorry, it was not well written: "…produces line brakes on **some** screen widths. **In those cases** I would like to shorten…"